# trouble compiling against static library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, unix-ar

I have created a static library, `libstuff.a`, with `gcc` and `ar`.  I've installed the library in `/custom/lib/dir/` and the header files in `/custom/include/dir/`.  When I try to compile another application against the archive, I am running into issues.

The application I am trying to compile basically uses `gcc -L/custom/lib/dir/ -I/custom/include/dir/ -lstuff`.

When I attempt to compile, I get error about a function I declare in `stuff.h` and define in `stuff.c`.

```
main.c:51: undefined reference to `stuff_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I remove `libstuff.a` from `/custom/lib/dir/` the compiler complains `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstuff`.  If I put it back, it doen't complain.  So it's finding the archive correctly.

If I remove the line of code `#include "stuff.h"` from `main.c` gcc complains about `stuff_init` being undefined, so it's finding the headers correctly.

If I run `nm libstuff.a`, the output includes `0000000000000000 T stuff_init`.  So the function is defined in the archive file.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A shared library isn't created with `àr(1)`, and `libfoo.a` is a *static* library. Check your build instructions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say static instead of shared.  Thanks :)

Comment: You really should show your exact and complete linking command line.  "Basically" is fine, but not specific enough.

Comment: Is -lstuff *before* the object files(s) on the link line, or after it? It needs to be after it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't show your exact linking line, but the chances are you should (but don't) list the libraries after the object files:

```
gcc -o program main.o -L/custom/lib/dir -lstuff
```

If there's more than one object file outside of the libraries, then list them all before any of the libraries.  The `-L` options may go anywhere before the `-llib` option that uses a library from the given directory.

Comment: That solved it.  I had my `-l` and `-L` flags appearing before my object files.  Thanks!